# What is the most efficient way to read a large CSV file ( 10 M+ records) located on S3 (AWS) with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, amazon-s3, dask

I've been trying to find the fastest way to read a large csv file ( 10+ million records) from S3 and do a couple of simple operations with one of the columns ( total number of rows and mean).
I have ran a couple of  tests, and the fastest so far was creating a dask dataframe, but I am wondering if there is any other alternative out there that may make things even faster.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Test 1. Pandas read csv: 92.36531567573547 seconds

```
start_time = time.time()
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
path =my_csvS3
use_column=['tip_amount']
df= pd.read_csv(path,usecols=use_column)
print(df.count)
print (df["tip_amount"].mean())
print("%s seconds" % ((time.time())-(start_time)))
```

Test 2 Pandas read csv in chunks: 78.15214204788208 seconds

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
tp = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=use_column, iterator=True, chunksize=5000000)  # gives TextFileReader
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
print(df.count)
print (df["tip_amount"].mean())
print("%s seconds" % ((time.time())-(start_time)))
```

Test 3 dask dataframe: 54.183971881866455 seconds

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import time
start_time = time.time()
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
df = dd.read_csv(path)
df = df['tip_amount'] 
cols=['tip_amount']
dfp = df.compute()
print(len(dfp))
print (dfp.mean())
print("%s seconds" % ((time.time())-(start_time)))
```

Comment: You should measure how much time it takes for the downlaod alone, which should be bandwidth limited, i.e., there's no getting around that cost.

Comment: Side-note: Instead of processing the file within the Python program, you could use **Amazon Athena** to process the file. You can provide Athena with an SQL query and it can perform the query on the data within S3 _without_ having to download the data. You can also call Athena from your own Python program. (Athena uses Presto technology to perform fast, parallel queries.)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
dfp = df.compute()
```

is an antipattern for dask. You split up the load, btu then you form a single large dataframe in memory by concatenation. You would do better to compute what you want on the original chunks (note that `len` is special in python, so this is less tidy than it would be

```
dask.compute(df.shape[0], df.mean())
```

Also, you might find better performance with the distributed scheduler, even on a single machine, for some workloads. In this case, I believe most of the work is GIL-free, which is the critical consideration. Still, worth measuring the difference.

Additional: if you really only want one column, specify this in your `read_csv` - this goes for all backends!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @mdurant! I tested your ideas and it took a little longer than my 3rd test ( read_csv just the column I need and used the dask.compute (df.shape[0],df.mean()) from above...I am a little confuse because all you said make sense and it should save a few seconds at least...